# Disable USB charge!

Tags: charging, 7.0-nougat, nokia-3

> I just tried and found that you need to modify a file:
>
> ```
> sys/class/power_supply/usb/device/charge
> ```
>
> its default content is `1` which means 'enable charging' you need to set it to `0` to 'disable charging'
>
> ```
> $ su   
> $ echo 0 > /sys/class/power_supply/usb/device/charge
> ```
>
> I tested on Nexus 4 and it's working successfully.

user3395818 has posted this answer. I have Nokia 3 and it comes with Android 7 Nougat. I am new to Android. How to perform the above task?

Please explain in detail with steps.

Comment: Note that the content of `/sys` can heavily vary between different devices, and even if there is such a file there, some devices might not allow you to modify it, or the modification would not come into effect.

Comment: Also to add to what @Andy says, it may not work on all devices

Comment: It might make your question easier to understand if you [edit] and add a link to the answer you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is:

1. [Root](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCSGZ60DFt8) your phone (voids warranty, also risky if not handled
   properly).
2. Download any root explorer like [ES Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).
3. Go to that path you've given
4. Edit that file and set it's value to 0.

You can also choose [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) as that's the only thing in which you can execute that code.
I'll recommend not to root your new phone. That's upto you.